# Enterprise provisioning profile. Sign devices without adding them

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

please correct me. I had apple developer account and worked as individual developer. Right now I have access to the enterprise account. I have information that I can build app using an enterprise profile even without adding UDID to it. So it means I can build apps on all my devices without signing them on portal. Am I right?

Can someone link to some topic or tutorial how to make the profile like I've described of course it it makes sense. I am not sure maybe I am confused about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes in case of enterprise profile you don't need to add UDID of your device[or any one else's] in it, you can make build with it and can install it in any iOS device.

You can see some questions and answers about enterprise account
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)

Answer (score 1):

No using an iOS Enterprise Program distribution deployment method need not to enter every device id.

All you need is a distribution certificate for signing and a provisioning profile built for it. Note that ANYONE that has the profile can run the app on their device, although you can revoke the profile if necessary.

You are also given the standard test and Ad Hoc deployment mechanisms as with the standard Development Program. The Ad Hoc is limited to 100 devices, which I don't understand, but anyway, there it is.

You can visit [this](http://www.maas360.com/maasters/forums/mobile-app-management-mam/show/332/building-ios-apps-for-enterprise-deployment) link for your reference